# Simple mysqli_query Insert into table (auto_increment)

Tags: mysqli

msa6@outlook.com 
postArray ( [zip] => 81007 [st] => co [dist] => 13 [email] => msa6@outlook.com [pw] => msa12345 [sq] => hot [sa] => dog [comment] => 8/8 original ) 
INSERT INTO mbr (zip,st,dist,email,pw,sq,sa) VALUES (81007,co,13,msa6@outlook.com,msa12345,hot,dog) 
Problem in recording your member data. Please try again later. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@outlook.com,msa12345,hot,dog)' at line 1

Comment: How do I send the php code and the create table?  Can I email all?  I have it all together in a notepad file.

Comment: write the code( try to indent it)

Answer (score 0):

varchars or characters should be enclosed in single quotes
Example:

```
'msa6@outlook.com'
```